# What documents can I bring to prove my US citizenship when crossing the border from Canada to the United States without a passport?

Tags: usa, passports, canada, us-citizens, citizen

I am a resident of Canada and I recently renewed my US passport, but it has been three weeks since it was shipped and I still have not received it. I was planning to drive to the US this weekend, but I am not sure what I should do to prepare. The only two documents I have that could prove my citizenship are a social security card and a photocopy of my old passport. I do not have access to my birth certificate, but I do have a BC registered vehicle and drivers license. Should I cancel my plans?

Comment: How did you get US citizenship? (e.g. born in the US? naturalized? born abroad to US citizen parent?)

Comment: @user102008
Sorry should have clarified, born in the US.

Comment: Do you have another citizenship, and another passport?

Answer (score 3):

I think that your photocopy of your old US passport should work, since the passport establishes your US citizenship and the authenticity of the information can be verified from databases. However, you should be prepared for them to temporarily detain you so they can verify your passport information.

Comment: Much appreciated, a long wait is definitely something initial research indicated. Maybe this is a question that's entirely dependent on random chance but is there any way to know how long that detainment could last? I imagine without an official piece of ID it would be quite a wait, possibly to the point that the trip just isn't worth the hassle.